# Sender Details of Google Cast SDK Developer Console

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have a free and paid version of my app. They are separate apk files. The package names, for example, are com.mycompany.thefreeapp and com.mycompany.thepaidapp.

When entering data in the "Google Cast SDK Developer Console" under Android package name, what do I put in the "Sender Details" for the package: which package? or do i need to create two applications and thus have two separate application ids?

Thanks,Jim

Answer (score 0):

For now you can choose to publish any one that you want to promote.

Comment: Both of the versions, free and paid, will have casting capabilities. I will then be promoting both. And it is no problem programmatically to have two different application IDs.